# material-ui: Autocomplete with value and inputValue stored together

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

**Goal:**
It's about the Material Autocomplete from material-ui for React in variant `freeSolo`. I understand that one is asked to handle `value` and `inputValue` independently, but because Formik and Yup are used to save the state and apply validation I would prefer to have only one value outside. For splitting this increases complexity in the outer code noticeably.

**Attempt:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-a-single-state-v442c?file=/demo.tsx
Is an example where I set the prop `inputValue` to `value.title || ''` and in `onInputChange` I check if the inputValue matches an existing option and otherwise create a new object, both to mimic `onChange`.

**Issue:**
Unfortunately, the list does not become filtered anymore. I had added some logging in my attempt was everything worked as expected and I can't infer what issue the component runs into. I hope anyone has some idea or ideally working code? So again, my overall goal is to have only one value representing the state and that, therefore, needs to be an object.

Answer (score 1):

So I realised this can not be done because the states `value` and `inputValue` update at different times. `value` is only affected by `inputValue` once the user clears the input completely, setting `inputValue` to `''` and `value` becoming `null`. So the asynchronous nature does not allow storing it in a single value in a clean way.